# kops update cluster failed with `error doing DNS lookup for NS records` `no such host`

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

## Envs

```
$ kops version
Version 1.18.2 (git-84495481e4)

Kubernetes Cluster Version: 1.18.10
```

## What I want to do

I want to create a Kubernetes cluster at my domain `xway.me`.

I found [this article](https://zerotoprod.com/posts/k8s-on-aws-kops-terraform/) and try that.

I created a cluster and tried to print the terraform file as output but it failed.

```
$ kops update cluster \
  --out=. \
  --target=terraform \
  --state s3://xway.me-kops \
  --name xway.me

error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "xway.me": lookup xway.me on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
```

## What I tried

[Error doing DNS lookup for NS records when using a Private DNS zone #781](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/781)

I add the `--dns private`

But I got `unknown flag: --dns`.

[Installing Kubernetes on AWS with kops](https://deepdive.tw/2017/01/04/installing-kubernetes-on-aws-with-kops/)

Now my resolv.conf is here

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search ad.oit.ac.jp
```

I add this code in the /etc/resolv.conf.

```
search xway.me
```

Then I got this error.

```
error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "xway.me": lookup xway.me on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
```

adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` is also failed

```
error doing DNS lookup for NS records for "xway.me": lookup xway.me on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
```

using kops create:

```
$ kops create cluster --name xway.me --state s3://xway.me-kops

cluster "xway.me" already exists; use 'kops update cluster' to apply changes
```

## I want to know

How can I succeed in running `kops update cluster`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using private DNS records, they will not typically resolve locally. You need a DNS forwareder hosted in a VPC that has the private route53 record enabled.

The kOps record doesn't expose anything particularly sensitive, but if you do not want to use a public record, an option is to use a [Gossip cluster](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/gossip/).

There is a [known issue with combining gossip with terraform](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/2990) though.